django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet, on django channels
My app run both using HTTP and Websocket using django channels. I am preparing for deployment and yet when I run daphne MarketPlace.asgi:application it throws this error. I am not sure if I had circular imports because my User model has been used a lot on other models from other applications.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luser/.local/share/virtualenvs/MarketPlace-8dI9Cb42/bin/daphne", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(CommandLineInterface.entrypoint())
  File "/home/luser/.local/share/virtualenvs/MarketPlace-8dI9Cb42/lib/python3.10/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 171, in entrypoint
    cls().run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/luser/.local/share/virtualenvs/MarketPlace-8dI9Cb42/lib/python3.10/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 233, in run
    application = import_by_path(args.application)
  File "/home/luser/.local/share/virtualenvs/MarketPlace-8dI9Cb42/lib/python3.10/site-packages/daphne/utils.py", line 17, in import_by_path
    target = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/luser/Desktop/MarketPlace/./MarketPlace/asgi.py", line 11, in <module>
    from chats.routing import websocket_urlpatterns
  File "/home/luser/Desktop/MarketPlace/./chats/routing.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import consumers
  File "/home/luser/Desktop/MarketPlace/./chats/consumers.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .models import Conversation, Message
  File "/home/luser/Desktop/MarketPlace/./chats/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from accounts.models import User
  File "/home/luser/Desktop/MarketPlace/./accounts/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
  File "/home/luser/.local/share/virtualenvs/MarketPlace-8dI9Cb42/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/luser/.local/share/virtualenvs/MarketPlace-8dI9Cb42/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 59, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/luser/.local/share/virtualenvs/MarketPlace-8dI9Cb42/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 129, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/luser/.local/share/virtualenvs/MarketPlace-8dI9Cb42/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/luser/.local/share/virtualenvs/MarketPlace-8dI9Cb42/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 138, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Anyone who is has an idea of how to solve this error? Please help.

Remember, the Daphne service on the server is running multiple instances or Python applications asynchronously for our web server and web sockets. It works between the Apache code and the Django server code to redirect web traffic where it needs to go.
Juxtaposed to other setups where you might connect to another server's websocket, we are connecting to our own server.
After deploying to a live server in production, you therefore need to redirect traffic to the applications which are running local relative to our server. Instead of connecting via http and ws, we need to connect via https and wss. The solution is to redirect all wss traffic to the local port where the websocket ws is running.
Consider the following Apache server configuration:
    ...
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:8001%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
ProxyPass /wss/ wss://127.0.0.1:8001/
ProxyPassReverse /wss/ wss://127.0.0.1:8001/
...
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/ca_bundle.crt
...

Then you have to start the server, and so at production level you are going to need a Docker container or some methodology to keep the code running. The command to run on a live server is a bit different, your web traffic is open on port 443 which is where your Apache server configuration should begin accepting traffic.
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 django_project.asgi:application // Local Development Level
daphne -e ssl:443:privateKey=key.pem:certKey=crt.pem django_project.asgi:application // Production Level

This should solve your issue as long as you are careful about what you are doing in your server configuration. Make sure you have your website up and running on a domain before using Daphne if you are having trouble directing traffic on port 443.
